# Zoho Api Oauth v.2 | Why does it want to sign in at the User Authorization Request?

Tags: php, api, zoho

I read it; (https://sheet.zoho.com/help/api/v2/#authorization)

[image]

Note: I know for a fact the URL is working. If I copy and paste it in the browser, everything is fine.

How do I get this code(Authorization) on my server side?

**I'm trying this on my server (php-curl):**

```
<?php
$uri = 'www.xxx.com/zoho_return.php';
$scope = 'ZohoSheet.dataAPI.UPDATE,ZohoSheet.dataAPI.READ';
$clientid = '1000.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$zoho_client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$accestype = 'offline';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=' . 
       $scope . '&client_id=' . $clientid . '&response_type=code&access_type=' . 
       $accestype . '&redirect_uri=' . $uri . '';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
curl_close($ch);
echo 'redirectURL: '.$redirectURL.'<br><br>';
echo 'header: '.$html;
```

**Response on chrome:**

**redirectURL:** https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoSheet.dataAPI.UPDATE,ZohoSheet.dataAPI.READ&client_id=1000.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&access_type=online&redirect_uri=www.xxx.com/zoho_return.php

**header:** HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: ZGS Date: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 22:48:43 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive Set-Cookie: a8c61fa0dc=8db261d30d9c85a68e92e4f91ec8079a; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1 Set-Cookie: iamcsr=108a1f8a-29cf-4408-bbaf-113f8c42a3d7;path=/;Secure;priority=high Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Location: https://accounts.zoho.com/signin?servicename=AaaServer&serviceurl=%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Fauth%3Fscope%3DZohoSheet.dataAPI.UPDATE%252CZohoSheet.dataAPI.READ%26client_id%1000.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26response_type%3Dcode%26access_type%3Donline%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fxxx.com%252Fzoho_return.php Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000

Answer (score 2):

Zoho CRM API v2 supports only [Authorization Code Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) which works in the browser as you mentioned.

The case here is that you have to use [Password Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/) to get the access token directly if you have a valid credentials which is not supported by Zoho.

You need to do some research about the [OAuth 2.0](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth2-the-complete-guide/).

Simply the answer is "**You can not get the Authorization Code from your PHP code**".